# How to annotate a List in Hibernate Envers?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a list object in my properties. So should I annotate it like this to have this object audited in the tables?

```
@OneToMany
private List<DaCust> duaCstdnsList = newArrayList<DaCust>();
```

And also is this right? ORG_ID is the foreign key to OrgAdd.

```
@Column(name="ORG_ID")
private Long orgAdd;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
private OrgAdd orgAdd;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too broad, but here are some tips.

`@OneToMany` is generally accompanied with `mappedBy` attribute, which is populated with the name of the field in the target entity which represents the owning side of the relationship (since on database level a foreign key is in `DaCust` table). Take a look at the [documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) for more examples

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "property")
private List<DaCust> duaCstdnsList = newArrayList<DaCust>();
```

And, for `@ManyToOne` you don't need to explicitly map the join column to entity field. You use `@JoinColumn` instead.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
@JoinColumn(name="ORG_ID")
private OrgAdd orgAdd;
```